# Using Iceberg tables and time travel feature in AWS Quicksight

Tags: amazon-quicksight, apache-iceberg

I have Iceberg tables in AWS data catalog which I want to use to create dashboards in AWS QuickSight. The idea is to set a date paremter in QuickSight and then to be able to use it with Iceberg time travel feature. I.e. I'd like QuickSight to filter the data as of specific date using Iceberg capability to execute queries "as of timestamp" (e.g. select  * from    table FOR TIMESTAMP AS OF (timestamp '2022-12-01 22:00:00').

My questions are:

1. Does Quicksight support Iceberg tables as a data source?
2. Is it possible to use the time travel feature of Iceberg tables in Quicksight when writing custom sql queries for the data source?
3. Is it possible to use Quicksight parameter with Iceberg time travel?

If this is possible, it would be extremely powerful combination Iceberge timetravel + Quicksight dashboards. If it is not possible what is the best alternatives, assuming that my data are in Iceberg tables.

It seems that Quicksight can work with Icerberg tables as a data source, but I can't figure out if quciksight paramters somehow can be used im time travel for Iceberg tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Iceberg tables as a data source with the Athena connector, but you can't use the QuickSight parameters for time travel. QuickSight parameters don't interact with the datasets, they only apply to the following:

- Calculated fields (except for multivalue parameters)
- Filters
- Dashboard and analysis URLs
- Actions
- Titles and descriptions throughout an analysis

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-iceberg.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/parameters-in-quicksight.html